# Error using Workbook on remote server

Tags: c#, excel

I am using Koogra Excel BIFF/XLSX Reader Library to manipulate some excel info. Everything works fine when I run it locally but when I put it on my remote server I get errors.

This is the following code that works fine locally but breaks on the server.

```
if (month.ToString() == "1" ||
    month.ToString() == "2" ||
    month.ToString() == "3" ||
    month.ToString() == "4" ||
    month.ToString() == "5" ||
    month.ToString() == "6" ||
    month.ToString() == "7" ||
    month.ToString() == "8" ||
    month.ToString() == "9")
{
    string monthc = "0" + month;
    file = "\\\\atlanta2-0\\HOME\\Accounting\\FLOOD INVOICES\\" + 
        monthc.ToString() + year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) + ".xlsx";
}
else
{
    file = "\\\\atlanta2-0\\HOME\\Accounting\\FLOOD INVOICES\\" + 
        month.ToString() + year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) + ".xlsx";
}

try
{
    Workbook wb = new Workbook(file);
}
```

The last line gives me an exception that states the file does not contain a workbook which usually happens when the file does not exist. However, I can verify that the file exists, and it works fine locally. Any ideas? It's like it can't access the file????

I also tried doing something like this

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
```

before the `try` and putting `fi.Fullname` when I catch my exception and it gives me the full path which is correct.

Comment: As an aside: you can clean up your code by replacing that whole `if` construct with `string monthc = month.ToString().Length == 1 ? "0" + month.ToString() : month.ToString();`. As far as your actual question goes I believe there are potential problems with Interop in a server environment, although for starters I might try altering the statement you're using to open the workbook to something like `Workbook wb = xpApp.Workbooks.Open(file);`

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment about changing the workbook open command, I just realised that Koogra uses a different syntax to Interop. But my comment about cleaning up the `if` statement still stands.